# Use DatePicker with expand animation outside Form

Tags: swiftui

If I use DatePicker inside a Form, it will render just like I want. At first it is just one line with the label and the current value. When the user clicks, it will expand and show the date picker wheel.

Example:

```
Form {
    DatePicker(selection: $dueDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
        Text("Due date")
    }
}
```

Expands to this on user click:

[image]

Now the question is; is it possible to get this behaviour outside a Form? - The Form makes things look ugly in my context. I do not want the gray background or the drop shadow.

Do anybody have a solution for this, or is a custom implementation needed?

My first attempt with Form just around the DatePicker, gave me this: :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I have found something that seems to work.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("Due date")
            Text(formattedDate)
            Divider().background(Color.gray)
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                self.showSelect.toggle()
            }
        }
        if showSelect {
            DatePicker("", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date]).labelsHidden()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

I have not included all the logic, but this is a good place to start.